# Ошибка при установке websocket-соединения

Tags: apache, nginx, websocket

На сервере стоит nginx, за ним apache, поднят ratchet. Сам сайт с сервера я получаю без проблем, но при установке соединения через websocket периодически (где-то в 50% случаев) возникает одна из следующих ошибок:

- WebSocket connection to 'wss://мой-сайт.com/wss2/' failed: Error
  during WebSocket  handshake: Unexpected response code: 502 (это чаще всего)
- WebSocket connection to 'wss://мой-сайт.com/wss2/' failed: Error
  during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503
- WebSocket connection to 'wss://мой-сайт.com/wss2/' failed:
  Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED

Нагрузки на процессор нет. Пока стоял один apache, всё работало без сбоев. Что я настроил не так?

Comment: я бы посмотрел nginx-овские error-логи и сделал бы максимально подробными логи ratchet - проблема в нём. надеюсь, nginx обращается напрямую к ratchet? nginx и ratchet на одном сервере? в одном докере?

Comment: @norbomen error-логи nginx, можно сказать, пустые. Одна-единственная запись: *4301 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094085:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ccs received early) while SSL handshaking, хотя ошибки валятся постоянно. Nginx и ratchet на одном сервере, но, думаю, обращение идет через apache.

Comment: убирай из этой цепочки апач если без него можно обойтись. т.е. настраивай так чтобы nginx проксировал запрос сразу в ratchet

Comment: @norbomen а как это сделать?